# How to create a resizeable view in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uitouch

Hi I am creating  a application in which I have to create different type of stretchable views like oval , circular, octal by touching its corners.

I have found some Similar question but its works only for square and only in length and width.

[Similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209445/how-to-create-resizable-view-with-handlers-on-sides-to-stretch-or-resize-in-ios)

Some thing like various option present in to select eyes, lips mouth in modifaces applications... I have to select area like that.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't have any idea from where should I start. Just tried On touchstart get the current point of the view and on touchEnd Replace the view points with the Endpoint...

Comment: Why this question is downvote ??? Atleast give a comment for that, So that I can improve my question in future...

Comment: @Apple I would like suggest you please whenever you need any help from SO community, just show your efforts before asking, like what you have tried so far and try to post relevant code here, so no one will give you donwvote etc. and even you will get more help, btw now your question is again normal 1-1 = 0 vote, **but don't forget to put the code where you need help**

Comment: @RDC thanks... But in this question I  didn't know from where should I start and what ever I didn't get the success even though I don't know I am on right track or not.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be drawing necessary shapes (for example: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/draw-circle-triangle-and-rectangle-in-iphone/)

And upon touchstart/touchMovement - simply redraw it using new coordinates.

You will have to think a smart way to know - which shape side should be changed.

For example - imagine - you programmatically draw a elipse in the middle of screen.

Then You touch somewhere at the right side near elipse line. You calculate - which elipse side is closer to touched point, and then - when moving finger - simply redraw each time - so that only necessary side would change position.